# UIWebView eats ~20mb memory

Tags: memory-leaks, uikit, uiwebview

So, after running spme tests with my app to determine the cause for extremely high memory usage, I found out that UIWebview was behind it. I got a hidden webView where I perform some operations, but the point is when I tell the webview to download the URL requests, memory consuption rises like 20-25mb which is not very good. I am not doing anything else with the view, I only tell it to load the page. Any solutions or has someone encountered similar? Thanks..

Comment: Before trying to reduce `UIWebView`'s memory consumption, do you _need_ to use `UIWebView`? Couldn't you use `NSURLConnection` to retrieve the content?

Comment: I have to run javascript on the page to trigger ajax component load. So NSURLConnection isn't an option.